# IS it the wrong time to get into the equity market immediately after large gains?

Tags: stocks, india

I was planning to get into a few equity MF's (till now I've had > 90% investments in Debt funds and Fixed deposits), but looking at the performance, most have had massive gains in the last 1-2 months.

My gut feeling tells me its not a good idea to invest into equity at this time since stock indexes and NAV's are mostly at historical highs.  IS there any professional advice about such situations?

Answer (score 2):

Its best to dollar cost average adding say 5%-10% a quarter into the fund.

That's what Clark Howard would suggest.

Also make sure you do not need the money for 5 years, then you should be okay.

Its tough to lose money if you keep your money there for a long period of time.

Comment: A quick spreadsheet shows 14 5 year periods of the last 100 having negative returns. And another 8 with returns that didn't keep up with inflation. An 80% success rate might not be enough depending on one's risk tolerance.

Answer (score 2):

If your gut told you to buy during the depths of '09, your gut might be well-calibrated.

The problem is stock market declines during recessions are frequently not that large relative to the average long run return of 9%:

[image]

A better strategy might be hold a percentage in equities based upon a probability distribution of historical returns.  This becomes problematic because of changes in the definition of earnings and the recent inflation stability which has encouraged high valuations:

[image]

Cash flow has not been as corrupted as earnings now, and might be a better indicator:

[image]

This obviously isn't perfect either, but returns can be improved.

Since there is no formulaic way yet conventionally available, the optimal primary strategy is still buy & hold which has made the most successful investor frequently one of the richest people on the planet for decades, but this could still be used as an auxiliary for cash management reserves during recessions once retired.

Comment: +1 "buy and hold". Don't gamble, don't play, invest.

Answer (score 0):

"Past results are not a predictor of future results." There is no explicit upper bound on a market, and even if individual companies' values were remaining unchanged one would expect the market to drift upward in the long term. Plus, there's been some  shift from managing companies for dividends to managing stocks for growth, which will tend to increase the upward push.

Trying to time the market -- to guess when it's going to move in any particular direction -- is usually closer to gambling than investing.

The simplest answer remains a combination of buy-and-hold and dollar-cost averaging. Buy at a constant number of dollars per month (or whatever frequency you prefer), and you will automatically buy more when the stock/fund is lower, less when it is higher. That takes advantage of downturns as buying opportunities without missing out on possible gains at the other end.

Personally, I add a bit of contrarian buying to that -- I increased my buying another notch or two while the market was depressed, since I had money I wouldn't need any time soon (buy and hold) and I was reasonably confident that enough of the market would come back strongly enough that I wasn't at significant risk of losing the investment. That's one of the things which causes me to be categorized as an "aggressive investor" even though I'm operating with a very vanilla mix of mutual funds and not attempting to micromanage my money. My goal is to have the money work for me, not vice versa.